# Generic build adding fields

Tags: macros, haxe

Consider this code:

http://try.haxe.org/#5AD6e

```
class Test
{
    public static function main()
    {
        var foo = new FluentFoo(null, { bar: 1 }).hello();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public function new(options:{ bar:Int }) {}

    public function hello()
    {
        trace("Hi there");
    }
}

class Fluent
{
    private var parent:Null<Fluent>;

    public function new(parent:Null<Fluent>)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public function end()
    {
        if(parent != null) {
            return parent;
        }

        throw 'Top level already reached';
    }
}

class FluentFoo extends Fluent
{
    public var base:Foo;

    public function new(parent:Null<Fluent>, options:{ bar:Int })
    {
        super(parent);

        base = new Foo(options);
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        base.hello();

        return this;
    }
}
```

I want to generate classes such as FluentFoo automatically.

In pseudohaxe code:

```
import haxe.Constraints.Constructible;

class Test
{
    public static function main()
    {
        var foo = new Fluent<Foo>(null, { bar: 1 }).hello();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public function new(options:{ bar:Int }) {}

    public function hello()
    {
        trace("Hi there");
    }
}

@:generic
@:genericBuild(FluentMacro.build())
class Fluent<T:Constructible<Dynamic -> Void>>
{
    private var parent:Null<Fluent>;
    private var base:T;

    public function new(parent:Null<Fluent>, options:Dynamic)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.base = new T(options);
    }

    public function end()
    {
        if(parent != null) {
            return parent;
        }

        throw 'Top level already reached';
    }
}

class FluentMacro
{
    public static function build()
    {
        //Get "T" public methods
        //Add them to class calling this genericBuild method (in this example to Fluent_Foo)
        //Modify them so they return "this"
    }
}
```

I know that I can't use `@:build` as all I'd get from `Context.getLocalType` would be `TInst(Fluent,[TInst(Fluent.T,[])])`.

However, I'm not completely understanding haxe manual on generic builds - they are under the same section "Type building macros" as normal `@:build`, yet the `build` method is expected to return `ComplexType`, and not an array of fields. Is it possible at all to add fields in `@:genericBuild`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bit more complex than I anticipated, but I did it. For other people to use: https://github.com/Misiur/Fluent